# Can Conditional compilation symbols be used within T4 templates

Tags: t4, conditional-compilation

I have a T4 template that is used with the TextTemplatingFilePreprocessor to generate a class that I can then use to generate the output of the template.

At the start of the T4 template I import several namespaces. E.g.

```
<#@ import namespace="Company.ProductX.Widgets" #>
<#@ import namespace="Company.ProductX.Services" #>
//...
```

I'd like to use [Preprocessor Directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to switch out these imports with another set of namespaces (which provide the same interfaces but differing functionality to ProductX). E.g.

```
<#
#if(ProductX)
{
#>
    <#@ import namespace="Company.ProductX.Widgets" #>
    <#@ import namespace="Company.ProductX.Services" #>
    //...
<#
}
#endif
#>
<#
#if(ProductY)
{
#>
    <#@ import namespace="Company.ProductY.Widgets" #>
    <#@ import namespace="Company.ProductY.Services" #>
    //...
<#
}
#endif
#>
```

With the above example the imports seem to create the corresponding using statements in the class regardless of the preprocessor directive. E.g.

```
using Company.ProductX.Widgets
using Company.ProductX.Services
using Company.ProductY.Widgets
using Company.ProductY.Services
```

Is there another way to use Preprocessors in T4 templates to affect the template itself rather than just the template output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example the preprocessor directive is injected into the generated output. What you could potentially do is having a ProductX.tt file that imports the correct namespace and uses <#@ include #> to include the template code.

Something like this (ProductX.tt):

```
<#@ import namespace="Company.ProductX.Widgets"  #>
<#@ import namespace="Company.ProductX.Services" #>

<#@ include file="TheTemplateCode.ttinclude"     #>
```

(ProductY.tt):

```
<#@ import namespace="Company.ProductY.Widgets"  #>
<#@ import namespace="Company.ProductY.Services" #>

<#@ include file="TheTemplateCode.ttinclude"     #>
```

I am not sure if this helps you but to be honest I am struggling a little bit with the use-case here.

Comment: We use such 'header' templates to do this and find it works quite well.  There isn't a way to insert conditionals around directives that's built in to the product.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This sounds like a good work around. Once I've got it working I'll mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

New idea for an old question.

It might be possible to use a [Custom T4 Text Template Directive Processor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126315.aspx) to pass through arbitrary code to the T4 output.

The custom directive processor would need to be registered on each machine to use it.

Comment: You could write a custom directive processor that was essentially a custom include directive, yes.  It's a lot of work compared to the header template approach though.